# How may I get Kotlin enum same behaviours as cpp ones

Tags: enums, kotlin

I'd like to get the same behaviour as cpp:

```
enum dxgi_format_gli
{
    DXGI_FORMAT_R64_UINT_GLI = 1,
    DXGI_FORMAT_R64_SINT_GLI
}
```

where `DXGI_FORMAT_R64_UINT_GLI` gets 1 and the next gets 2

the closest I got is:

```
private var counter: Int = 2;

enum class dxgi_format_gli(i: Int = counter++) {

    DXGI_FORMAT_R64_UINT_GLI(1),
    DXGI_FORMAT_R64_SINT_GLI()
}
```

However I'd like it, of course, to be dynamic, that is whenever I call the constructor with a parameter, save that one in `counter` and all the following constructors increment and get it..

I already made it in java:

```
public enum Dxgi_format_gli {

    DXGI_FORMAT_R64_UINT_GLI(1),
    DXGI_FORMAT_R64_SINT_GLI;

    public final int value;

    private static class Counter {

        private static short value = 0;
    }

    private Dxgi_format_gli() {
        value = Counter.value;
        Counter.value++;
    }

    private Dxgi_format_gli(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        Counter.value++;
    }
}
```

But I didn't make it using Kotlin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to set the value and move the increment around to make it work - so the initial counter and value are the same.

```
enum class Dxgi_format_gli {

  DXGI_FORMAT_R64_UINT_GLI(1),
  DXGI_FORMAT_R64_SINT_GLI;

  val value: Int

  private object Counter {
    var value: Int = 0
  }

  constructor() {
    Counter.value++
    value = Counter.value.toInt()
  }

  private constructor(value: Int) {
    this.value = value
    Counter.value = value
  }
}
```

Comment: Very cool! You emulated the best feature of C++! See my answer for the short way.

Answer (score 7):

Every `enum` already has an auto-generated property `ordinal`:

```
enum class A {a, b, c}

A.a.ordinal  // 0
A.b.ordinal  // 1
A.c.ordinal  // 2
```

So technically the easiest way to get what you want is `dxgi_format_gli.DXGI_FORMAT_R64_UINT_GLI.ordinal + 1` (I have no idea why don't you want to start with `0` 0_o)

You may replace the code in the @griffio's answer with this:

```
enum class Dxgi_format_gli {

  DXGI_FORMAT_R64_UINT_GLI,
  DXGI_FORMAT_R64_SINT_GLI;

  val value = ordinal + 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I don't start from `0` because this is the cpp code I am porting (there is an explanation btw)

Comment: Cool suggestion `val value = ordinal + 1` voddan, +1 :p